# postgresql insert recursive data

Tags: database, postgresql, recursion, tree, common-table-expression

I want to insert a batch of recursive data, each row has a `parent_id` references to its parent row's id in the same table. What's the fast way to insert all the rows?

```
CREATE TABLE subjects (
  id      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name    CHARACTER VARYING(128)      NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE items (
  id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  subject_id INTEGER                  NOT NULL REFERENCES subjects (id),
  content TEXT,
  parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES items (id)
);
```

I can wait each returning id and then set it to the `parant_id`, but this would cause every insert waits for its parent to complete.
The following insert seems only works for 1 parent and 1 child, what if I also want to insert a subject has a `item 2` and `item 2` has a `child 2`? I don't have to use this query, I just want to know a better way to do this.

```
WITH s AS
  ( INSERT INTO subjects (NAME)
   VALUES ('some subject') RETURNING *),
     i AS
  ( INSERT INTO items (subject_id, content)
   VALUES (
             (SELECT id
              FROM s), 'item parent 1') RETURNING *)
INSERT INTO items (subject_id, content, parent_id)
VALUES (
          (SELECT id
           FROM s), 'item parent 1 child 1',
          (SELECT id
           FROM i))
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8f7f2/1/0)

Comment: I'm not sure you can actually do this without waiting for the previous insert to end as there is recursive referential integrity in your `items` table.
If I were you I would use the RECURSIVE definition and set up a sort of iterator working on your string value!